# Can't figure out how Sangria does conversion from GraphQL type to Scala type

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria, graphql-schema

## Context

I have setup like so:

```scala
case class Foo(
  option_enum_vector_field: Option[Vector[Bar]] // Bar is complicated object which can't be easily expressed with sangria default scalars, but can be created by using Bar.apply(enum_str: String)
)

// My expected GraphQL input type for Bar
implicit val FooEnumFieldType = EnumType(
  "FooEnumFieldType",
  Some("description"),
  List(
    EnumValue("high", value = "high"),
    EnumValue("medium", value = "medium"),
    EnumValue("low", value = "low")
  )
)

val FooType = ObjectType(
  "FooType",
  "description",
  fields[Unit, Foo](
    Field("option_enum_vector_field", OptionType(ListType(FooEnumFieldType)), resolve = _.value.???),
  )
)
```

In `resolve = ctx => ctx.value.option_enum_vector_field` is what the result should be so it expects `Option[Vector[Bar]]` type. Because I put `OptionType(ListType(FooEnumFieldType))` as my GraphQL type there is a mismatch between types and compiler is swearing at me.

What I do not understand is where and how I should tell Sangria how to go from `FooEnumFieldType` GraphQL input to `Bar` type by taking enum value from client and doing `Bar.apply("high")` for example.

## Questions

1. How to define mappings from GraphQL enum types to Scala types in sangria?
2. How to get values passed from client in resolve function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ObjectType` for `Bar` to allow sangria to use it as an output type. The simplest method would be to derive the object type for `Bar` automatically.

```
implicit val BarType =
  deriveObjectType[Unit, Bar]()
```

This requires sangria to be able to convert all the elements of `Bar` so if that is not possible then a custom object may be required.

```
implicit val BarType: ObjectType[Unit, Bar] = ObjectType(
  "Bar",
  "Bar",
  fields[Unit, Bar](
    Field("id", IDType, resolve = _.value.id),
    // other fields
  )
)
```

Sangria use this `implicit` value to convert `Bar` values to `BarType` values which, in turn, can be used to generate the JSON output as required. `ObjectType` is a *typeclass* that can be used in other sangria methods to process objects of type `Bar`.

Finally the "option_enum_vector_field" field needs to have the appropriate type:

```
Field("option_enum_vector_field", OptionType(ListType(BarType)), resolve = _.value.option_enum_vector_field),
```

[ If you are actually implementing a `mutation` then you need to create an instance of `InputObjectType` that performs the reverse mapping ]